# Accessing neighbour indices in a particular element of an array (python)

Tags: python

I have a two dimensional list like :

```
data = [[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

How can I access the index of the neighbours, where the value equals 1?

Expected output:

```
[[4, 5, 6], [0, 1, 2]]
```

For example, the indices of an array  data in first row at value 1 is 5, so I need to access its left and right side neighbour indices like 4 and 6. Same way for row 2.

Comment: can you add output formate?

Comment: and also mentioned count of 1 is always 1 in all subarray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One efficient solution is using FOR loops:

```
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(10):
        if a[i][j]==1:
            print(str(i)+' '+str(j))
```

Comment: This is O(n^2). Perhaps remove the word 'efficient' from the statement.

Comment: That's not optimized, I would be glad to hear the meaning of efficient in your opinion.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand description well (please clarify) , maybe you can try this one. Additionally, you can check edge case where there is no 1, or no left or right .

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

if __name__ == "__main__":
  indices = np.where(a == 1)[1]
  indices = indices.reshape(-1,1)
  indices = np.concatenate([indices-1,indices,indices+1],-1)
  print(indices)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If using lists, here is a one approach which identifies the indexes of the neighbours of 1. As a caveat, this will fail with a index out of range, if the 1 value is the first of last element in the list.

Input:

```
data = [[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

Example:

```
[[i-1, i, i+1] for sub in data for i, j in enumerate(sub) if j == 1]
```

Output:

```
[[4, 5, 6], [0, 1, 2]]
```

Comment: Then less typing - ```[[i-1, i, i+1] for sub in data for i, j in enumerate(sub) if j]```  ;-)

Comment: @DanielHao - Fair play. Updated. Have kept `j == 1` in the event OP's actual data contains other values aside from [0, 1], as 1 was the value of interest.